# Storing the BMI in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Can anyone help me with my project for college?
I am trying to store the value of BMI into SQLite.

I have the databaseHelper setup and all that, just not sure how to store it while setting it to a TextView also.
I want to store and show the result.

The code below works and displays it, I just don't know how to store it also.

```
  package ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 import android.widget.NumberPicker;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import static ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy.R.id.imageViewBMI;

 public class BmiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi);

    final Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
     final NumberPicker weight = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.et_weight);
     final NumberPicker height = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.et_height);
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(imageViewBMI);


    weight.setMinValue(30);
    weight.setMaxValue(300);

    height.setMinValue(30);
    height.setMaxValue(300);

    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          //  int weightlbs = weight.getValue();
           // int heightcm = height.getValue();

           // int weights =  weight.getValue();
           // int heights = height.getValue();

           // String weightStr = String.valueOf(weights);
           // String heightStr = String.valueOf(heights);
           // double kg = 0.45;
            //String kgs = String.valueOf(kg);
           // double meter = 0.025;

            String heightStr = "" + (height.getValue());
            String weightStr = "" + (weight.getValue());



          // String heightStr = height.getText().toString();
          // String weightStr = weight.getText().toString();

            if (heightStr != null && !"".equals(heightStr)
                    && weightStr != null  &&  !"".equals(weightStr)) {
                double heightValue = Double.parseDouble(heightStr)/100;
                double weightValue = Double.parseDouble(weightStr);

                double bmi = weightValue/ (heightValue * heightValue) ;

                String bmiLabel;

                if (bmi <= 15) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.very_very_skinny);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.skinny);
                } else if (bmi > 15 && bmi <= 16) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.very_skinny);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.skinny);
                } else if (bmi > 16 && bmi <= 18.5) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.skinny);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.skinny);
                } else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi <= 25) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.normal);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);
                } else if (bmi > 25 && bmi <= 30) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.overweight);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fat);
                } else if (bmi > 30 && bmi <= 35) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_series_i);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fat);
                } else if (bmi > 35 && bmi <= 40) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_series_ii);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fat);
                } else {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_series_iii);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fat);

                }

                bmiLabel ="" + bmi;

              result.setText(bmiLabel);


            }


        }
    });

}
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////This is code for databasehelper
                  SQLiteDatabase db;

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table users (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
" name text not null, username text not null, password text not null, bmi double not null);";

public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context , DATABASE_NAME , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    this.db = db;

}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    this.onCreate(db);

}


public String searchPassstr(String et_username){
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select * from users";
    String unstr, passstr;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    passstr = "Password not Found!!";

    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{

            unstr = cursor.getString(2);


            if(unstr.equals(et_username)) {
                passstr = cursor.getString(3);
                break;
            }



        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    return passstr;
    }

public String getName() throws SQLException {
    String name = "";
    Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
            TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_NAME },
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            name = cursor.getString(0);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return name;
}

public String getUsername() throws SQLException {
    String username = "";
    Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
            TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_USERNAME },
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            username = cursor.getString(0);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();

    return username;
}

public String getResult() throws SQLException {
    String result = "";
    Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
            TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_BMI },
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            result = cursor.getString(0);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return result;
}



public void insertUser(RegRequest reg) {
db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

String query = "select * from users";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
int count = cursor.getCount();
values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
values.put(COLUMN_NAME, reg.getEt_name());
values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, reg.getEt_username());
values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, reg.getEt_password());

    values.put(COLUMN_BMI, reg.getResult());
  //  values.put(COLUMN_AGE, reg.getEt_password());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
db.close();
}
```

Comment: Well you will have to pass the bmi to your databaseHelper, in which ever way you have set it up. This otherwise isn't a real question

Comment: when i have passed previous values they have been for editText's and i am new to Android Studio and Sqlite. what sort of code would pass the bmi in this code?

Comment: From where have you learned how to use sqlite and databaseHelpers?

Comment: college currently in

Comment: Then i presume you will have some type of example of working with databases from which you developed your databaseHelper

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AsyncTask` to do database transactions.

Initialize `DataBaseHelper` object as:

```
DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
```

Get `SQLiteDatabase` reference as:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Use `ContentValues` to store required values

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("bmi", bmiValue)
contentValues.put("user_id", userID)
```

Then insert into the appropriate table as:

```
sqLiteDatabase.insert("<tableName>", null, contentValues);
```